# Displaying a matplotlib bar chart not working in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a bar chart for the amount of sales per year by month, I pass into the function a list of 12 elements corresponding to the amount of sales per month.

I process it and do all the relevant steps but the output is nothing like I want it to be.

Any ideas on whats wrong? Many Thanks

[Result Of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogfxr.png)
[image]

```
def BarChart(self,values):
    #Data 
    y1 = [values[0]]
    y2 = [values[1]]
    y3 = [values[2]]
    y4 = [values[3]]
    y5 = [values[4]]
    y6 = [values[5]]
    y7 = [values[6]]
    y8 = [values[7]]
    y9 = [values[8]]
    y10 = [values[9]]
    y11 = [values[10]]
    y12= [values[11]]

    x = np.arange(len(y1))

    # Plot data 
    # use zorder to put bares in front of grid.
    bar_width = 10
    plt.bar(x,y1,width=bar_width,color='red',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y2,width=bar_width,color='blue',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y3,width=bar_width,color='green',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y4,width=bar_width,color='orange',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y5,width=bar_width,color='purple',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y6,width=bar_width,color='yellow',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y7,width=bar_width,color='white',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y8,width=bar_width,color='pink',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y9,width=bar_width,color='gold',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y10,width=bar_width,color='black',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y11,width=bar_width,color='silver',zorder=2)
    plt.bar(x+bar_width,y1,width=bar_width,color='grey',zorder=2)

    #Labels
    #Adjust x until its in center.
    plt.xticks(x+bar_width*2,["January","Feburary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"])
    plt.title('MOT Analysis Chart')
    plt.xlabel('Months')
    plt.ylabel('Amount Of MOTs')

    red = mpatches.Patch(color='red',label="January")
    blue = mpatches.Patch(color='blue',label="Feburary")
    green = mpatches.Patch(color='green',label="March")
    orange = mpatches.Patch(color='orange',label="April")
    purple = mpatches.Patch(color='purple',label="May")
    yellow = mpatches.Patch(color='yellow',label="June")
    white = mpatches.Patch(color='white',label="July")
    pink = mpatches.Patch(color='pink',label="August")
    gold = mpatches.Patch(color='gold',label="September")
    black = mpatches.Patch(color='black',label="October")
    silver = mpatches.Patch(color='silver',label="November")
    grey = mpatches.Patch(color='grey',label="December")

    plt.legend(handles=[red,blue,green,orange,purple,yellow,white,pink,gold,black,silver,grey])

    plt.grid(axis='y')

    plt.show()
```

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLDoC.png)

Comment: In your example code, `x = [0]` (`len(y1) = 1`, so `np.arange(len(y1))` only has one element)

Comment: Yes thats correct, but i dont know how to change it so it works for my case. any ideas?

Comment: See my suggested answer below. The x-coordinate needs to be different for each bar you want to plot. Good problem formulation, by the way (MWE, result of code).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

def BarChart(values):
    bar_width = 10
    x = np.arange(len(values))*bar_width

    colors = ("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "yellow", "white", "pink", "gold", "black", "silver", "grey")
    months = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    handles = [mpatches.Patch(color=c,label=l) for c, l in zip(colors, months)]

    # Plot data 
    # use zorder to put bares in front of grid.

    for i, y in enumerate(values):
        plt.bar(x[i], y, width=bar_width, color=colors[i], zorder=2)

    #Labels
    #Adjust x until its in center.
    plt.xticks(x, months, rotation=90)
    plt.title('MOT Analysis Chart')
    plt.xlabel('Months')
    plt.ylabel('Amount Of MOTs')        

    plt.legend(handles=handles, ncol=2)
    plt.grid(axis='y')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

y = np.arange(12) + 1
BarChart(y)
```

Comment: This has worked really well, but now the bars are joined side by side so the labels are redundent, how do i spread out the bars sop each label can be seen on the x axis?

Comment: Rotated them and that works and the rest of the code works amazingly. with only one slight issue, the labels arent lining up with the correct bars as in the labels start 2 bars to late so first label for january is on the 3rd bar. any ideas?

Comment: That's because in your old code, you had `plt.xticks(x+2*bar_width, ...)`. See code above

Comment: I just changed that before i saw your comment, but thanks very much it all works amazingly well now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please mark this answer for future reference.